# Rails translate rich text with Mobility and ActionText as backend?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actiontext, mobility

[Mobility](https://github.com/shioyama/mobility) has a syntax to translate Rails ActiveRecord strings and text:

```rb
class Word < ApplicationRecord
  extend Mobility
  translates :content
end
```

On the other hand, here is the syntax to declare rich text with [ActionText](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_text_overview.html):

```rb
class Word < ApplicationRecord
  has_rich_text :content
end
```

How can these be combined to efficiently translate rich text with Mobility? Ideally I want to avoid doing a double-join [as suggested here in the context of Globalize](https://github.com/rails/actiontext/issues/32#issuecomment-450653800), i.e. avoiding needing to join a translation table then joining a rich-text table.

There seems to be an opportunity to combine both steps using the ActionText table, which is already a polymorphic relationship similar to the key-value backend, so that the translation would be available "for free" with no performance impact compared to untranslated rich text.

Comment: Please post this as a feature request to the Mobility repo, it's probably something many people would like to have.

Comment: @ChrisSalzberg I did :-) https://github.com/shioyama/mobility/issues/385

Comment: Thanks! Commented on it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now possible with [Mobility Action Text](https://github.com/sedubois/mobility-actiontext/).

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is why `action-text-attachment` tag are not rendered in the views yet.